# readthedocs build failing but local sphinx build working

Tags: github, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I am getting the following error on readthedocs when I try to manually build docs or when a build is triggered by a push to the GitHub repo:

```
python2.7 -mvirtualenv --no-site-packages --no-download /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/my_project_name/envs/latest
New python executable in /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/my_project_name/envs/latest/bin/python2.7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2328, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 713, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 925, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1231, in install_python
    shutil.copyfile(executable, py_executable)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 40] Too many levels of symbolic links: '/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/my_project_name/envs/latest/bin/python2.7'
Command time: 0s Return: 1
```

The builds seemed to spontaneously stop working and reverting to old versions of docs that previously worked does not help. I am running

```
sphinx-autobuild . _build_html
```

to build the docs.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle changed the javadoc compiler to be more strict in jdk1.8.0_121, which broke the build.

From the release notes: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u121-relnotes-3315208.html

> The javadoc tool will now reject any occurrences of JavaScript code in
> the javadoc documentation comments and command-line options, unless
> the command-line option, --allow-script-in-comments is specified.
>
> With the --allow-script-in-comments option, the javadoc tool will
> preserve JavaScript code in documentation comments and command-line
> options. An error will be given by the javadoc tool if JavaScript code
> is found and the command-line option is not set.
>
> JDK-8138725 (not public)

Answer (score 1):

The problem appeared to have been a problem on readthedocs.org's side with building images and is discussed in this GitHub issue

[readthedocs.org GitHub issue #2640](https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org/issues/2640)